# Post call for search data

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest

Here i need to search name in scroll,for that i  send search data query string in get call but i need to that in post.

Here is my server and client controller route and service.Also here i  handling search from server side.How to post data which user has been searched ,and pass that to client and server side.

```
 client controller service:

     'use strict';
     angular.module('details').factory('DetailService', ['$resource',
        function($resource) {
         return $resource('details', { 

         }, 
          searchUsers:{
                method: 'GET',
              }
           });
          }
          ]);
Angular controller:
         $scope.searchServer = function(searchData){

          DetailService.searchUsers({search:searchData},function(response){
          }, function(error){
              $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
          });
        }
 my Server side controller:
         exports.searchCust = function (req, res) {

          var strWhere = {
        corporateName: search
        };
       db.Customer.findAll({
        where: [strWhere],
            }).then(function (customers) {

              if (!customers) {
                 return res.status(400).send({
                message: 'Customer not found.'
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(customers);
        }
    })
                  };
       my server sideroute:
       app.route('/details').all(customersPolicy.isAllowed)
         .get(details.searchCust);
           app.param('search', details.searchCust);
        };
```

Comment: Ugh, your formatting is messed up

Comment: Seriously, you are asking people to help and can't even research the fundamental basics before or at least format your code. Markdown is not difficult and there are code formatters available on the web. It borders on the disrespectful to just throw something at the community and hope others will do your work. I am sure it still won't work, I have corrected the most glaring problems, but for the love of god, read about Angular, Node and the difference between JSONP and JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it out in all details as it looks like it was copy and pasted together without reading the basics. However, if you want POST requests, you need to set them both in the node-code and the Angular code, see below. What's more, Angular doesn't use JSONP, it uses JSON, so you need to set that. In the `searchUsers`-resource-call you only implemented the error-branch, so the results would just vanish. You'll find them in `$scope.searchResults` now.

**client controller service:**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('details').factory('DetailService', ['$resource',
function($resource) {
    return $resource('details', {},
        searchUsers: {
            method: 'POST',
        }
    });
}]);
```

**Angular controller:**

```
$scope.searchServer = function(searchData) {

    DetailService.searchUsers({
        search: searchData
    }, function(response) {
        $scope.status = "OK";
        $scope.searchResults = response;
    }, function(error) {
        $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
    });
}
```

**my Server side controller**

```
exports.searchCust = function(req, res) {

    var strWhere = {
        corporateName: search
    };
    db.Customer.findAll({
        where: [strWhere],
    }).then(function(customers) {

        if (!customers) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: 'Customer not found.'
            });
        } else {
            res.json(customers);
        }
    })
};
```

**my server sideroute:**

```
app.route('/details').all(customersPolicy.isAllowed)
    .post(details.searchCust);
app.param('search', details.searchCust);
};
```